# How to split a column into different parts with different sizes?

Tags: python

I have a column whose values are lists. as you see in the following image:
[columns image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OBFP.png)

I want the "sequence_movie_ids" column which is a list to be split into two columns, a column comprised of all the values except the last element of the list and another comprised the last element of the list.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `type(df['sequence_movie_ids'].iloc[0])` returns `list`:

- Either use the [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor to split the lists:

  ```py
  df['all_but_last'] = df['sequence_movie_ids'].str[:-1]
  df['only_last'] = df['sequence_movie_ids'].str[-1]
  ```
- Or use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

  ```py
  df['all_but_last'] = df['sequence_movie_ids'].apply(lambda x: x[:-1])
  df['only_last'] = df['sequence_movie_ids'].apply(lambda x: x[-1])
  ```

---

If `type(df['sequence_movie_ids'].iloc[0])` returns `str`, that means they are strings that just *look* like lists.

In that case, first parse them into real lists using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```py
from ast import literal_eval
df['sequence_movie_ids'] = df['sequence_movie_ids'].apply(literal_eval)
```

And then use the `all_but_last` and `only_last` code from above.

Comment: type(df['sequence_movie_ids'].iloc[0] returns lists, and your solution works! thanks

Answer (score 1):

if its a real list and not string, you can do like this:
`a = sequence_movie_ids[:len-1]` and `b = sequence_movie_ids[len-1]`